# Kapacitor - shift series to epoch start

Tags: kapacitor

Using a Kapacitor Batch script, how can I

- shift the time stamps of a time series to start at the epoche
- add a tag and
- store the result in a separate InfluxDB?

In other words: I’d like to run a “SELECT INTO” query, with the ELAPSED ns between measurements being used as the time stamp (and add a tag)?

Background: I’d like to extract the measurements taken during “experiments”, store them “time-neutralised” in a dedicated experiments-DB, in order to compare measurements of multiple experiments in a single Grafana chart.

Comment: `Kapacitor` is powerful but it has its limitation due to its age. Looking at your requirements I think it will be much easier for you to write a program to address it. For instance, in Javascript you can use `node-influx` as the database driver to read the data, alter them then using the driver to write it back.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my suspicion.